# C# Memory usage spike with static method System.Drawing.Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, memory

So I have a program that loads a bunch of files into a listview in preparation to upload. I just happen to have TaskManager open when I loaded 600 photos to stress test it and check responses times. I was shocked when memory spiked to over 1.2 gigs. I have a small helper class that validates the files are actually pictures and that is what is causing the spike. If I do not call that method, memory usage is constant. Not sure why this is happening.

I currently use a background worker to load the files and then update an observable collection that is bound to a listview.

```
    // Select File Populate worker:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private void select_file_populate_Start(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
    .
    .
    .
        // For each file selected, it will add it to the listview form.
        for (int i = 0; i < Selected_Files.Length; i++)
        {
            // This makes sure the same form is not add to the list again.
            bool duplicate = false;

            // Enumerates through the observable collection to see if there is a match for the file path.
            foreach (FileData entry in Selected_Files_Data)
            {
                if (entry.Path == Selected_Files[i])
                {
                    duplicate = true;
                }
            }

            // If the file is not a duplicate this will check the validity of the file.
            if (duplicate == false && Tools.validate_image(Selected_Files[i]))
            {
                Selected_Files_Buffer.Add(Selected_Files[i]);
            }
        }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

In the snip above , I call a helper method `Tools.validate_image(Selected_Files[i])` to validate the file is actually a photo.

Here is the code for that:

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static string filetype { get; set; }

    // Checks to make sure the image is valid.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static bool validate_image(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat file_format = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename).RawFormat;

            if (file_format.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg))
            {
                filetype = ".JPG";

                return true;
            }
            else if (file_format.Equals(System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png))
            {
                filetype = ".PNG";

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        catch //(Exception Ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but I did notice that you are calling System.Drawing.Image.FromFile() twice (potentially). You may be better off to save that off, and then just check the rawformat twice instead of creating the image twice.

Comment: I just noticed that and fixed it since you are correct as I was calling it twice. Edited my post.

Comment: You **must** [dispose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8th8381z(v=vs.110).aspx) an image.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov There are no memory leaks. It is just spiking and then returning to the base state of the program.

Comment: @DavidBentley Disposing does not fix memory leaks - it ensures that memory is reclaimed **in a deterministic manner**.  If you don't dispose of it, the memory will be reclaimed whenever the GC runs, which may be much later than you want.

Comment: @DStanley @AlexanderPetrov There does not look to be a way to dispose of `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat`

Comment: @DavidBentley You dispose of the _image_, not the _format_.  The problem is you've inlined it so there's no easy way to do that.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

.NET is a managed environment, meaning that unreferenced objects will remain in memory until the .NET Garbage Collector kicks in. So memory usage can surely spike until that happens.

The GC either kicks in automatically (usually not too frequently), or by being triggered manually, which you can do like this:

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

I would recommend to do this not too often, as it may hurt performance. What is 'too often' depends on your situation. Try doing it every 10, 50 or 100 files processed, while checking both max memory usage and CPU time spent in total.

Answer (score 1):

You should `Dispose` of the image as soon as you're done with it, which in your case is the instant you have determined the format. I would change

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat file_format = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename).RawFormat;
```

to

```
System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat file_format
using(var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename))
{
    file_format = image.RawFormat;
}  // the image will be disposed here, even if an exception is thrown.
```

I would also suggest adding `using System.Drawing` to the top of your file rather than fully qualifying the types in code - it makes it clearer what types you are using.